# Search and replace URL parts via apache htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'd like to rewrite URLS like:

`http://www.mydomain.tld/en/component/mycomponent/singlearticle/16-core/219-checked.html`

to

`http://www.mydomain.tld/en/articles/bycategory/16-core/219-checked.html`

Means the part "component/mycomponent/singlearticle" should become "articles/bycategory", but I have problems to build a rewrite rule for my .htaccess which cover that.

*Note: mod_rewrite is on (RewriteEngine on)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want only to rewrite this one url you need this.

```
RewriteRule ^en/component/mycomponent/singlearticle/16-core/219-checked.html$ http://www.mydomain.tld/en/articles/bycategory/16-core/219-checked.html [R=301,L]
```

**Edit:**

Then try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/component/mycomponent/singlearticle/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/en/articles/bycategory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then everything what came behind the singlearticle will be redirected to the other page. Perhaps you can try it. I can't test it here on the fly.

Comment: not only the URL, there are some others as well, one URL would be easy, but I have problems to find a rewrite rule for the parts of the URL.

Comment: i have test it now for you. Its working. Perhaps you have to set the RewriteBase to /.

Comment: You are right ... it is working with a "[L]" at the end. I think the problem from the stuff I tried was that the one rule I build kicks in and then another one is also applied ... the "[L]" fix that then.

Comment: oh sorry man :D you should write [R=301,L] its better for google.

Comment: I striped that from my response above, so other didn´t got confused with the HTTP redirection code if the stumbled across that. But yes you are absolutely right. thanks man :-)